# Solution Verification: Olympiad number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers such that $q=2p+1$

Prove that there exists a positive integer multiple of $q$ whose sum of decimal digits is at most $3$

I wasn't able to find the solution anywhere.

What I did: Assume $p,q$ are coprime to $10$ (the only situations where they aren't is where $p=2$ and $q=5$ in which case any value $10^a$ is a solution, or $p=5$, $q=11$ in which case $1001$ is a solution)

All congruences below are modulo $q$

Let us assume that there is no such multiple.

Now, by Fermat's little theorem, $10^{q-1}\equiv 1 $

$10^{2p}\equiv 1$

$10^p\equiv 1$ or $10^p\equiv -1$

In the latter case $10^p+1$ is a solution, contradicting the assumption.

So we consider the former case. Consider the tuple of residues modulo $q$ ; $A=(10^0,10^1... 10^{p-1})$

Clearly, $0$ (mod $q$) is not in this tuple because $10$ and $q$ are coprime. $2p$ can also not be there because if $10^w\equiv2p$ then $10^w+1$ is a solution.

We show by contradiction that $p$ (mod $q$) is not in this tuple:

Let us suppose $10^k\equiv p$

Then $2*10^k+1\equiv 2p+1\equiv 0$ which would make $2*10^k+1$ a solution, contradicting the assumption.

So the tuple $A$ contains $p$ elements and there are only $q-3=2p-2$ possible residues modulo $q$ (because $0$, $2p$ and $p$ are not there)

Now, let us assume all the residues are distinct. Then by the pigeonhole principle, there are 2 values $10^r, 10^s$ such that $10^r+10^s\equiv -1$, which would yield a solution, (by making $p-1$ pairs of resiudes $p+l$ and $p-l$ for $0<l<p$ which add up to $-1$)

Thus, $10^r+10^s+1$ is a solution.

If not all the values are distinct then assume $10^m\equiv 10^n$ Then $10^{|m-n|}\equiv 1$

Let $v=|m-n|$ Then $10^v\equiv 10^p\equiv 1$ and $gcd(v,p)=1$

It is easy to see that $10^{xv+yp}\equiv 1$ if the exponent is positive, for any integers $x,y$.

By Euclid's remainder algorithm, there are two numbers $x,y$ which satisfy $xv+yp=1$

So, $10^1\equiv 1$, a clear impossibility.

Is this solution complete?

Comment: @aman For "Then $10^v\equiv 10^p\equiv 1$ and $gcd(v,p)=1$", it's somewhat easier to use the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $10$ modulo $q$. In this case, the multiplicative order must divide $p$, so it's $1$ or $p$, but it can't be $1$, so it's $p$. Thus, $v$ must be an integral multiple of $p$, but as you wrote this is not possible.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks; that was certainly much more elegant than what I did!

Comment: It would be a little clearer to explain why $gcd (v,p)=1.$ That is,  $0\le m,n\le p-1$ with $m\ne n,$ so $1\le v= |m-n|<p,$ and $p$ is prime. Well done.

Comment: How are you applying PP currently? In your writeup, there are $2p-1$ possible residues (holes) and $p$ elements in $A$ (pigeons).

Comment: @CalvinLin You make pairs of the residues $r$ and $-r$ so that there must be 2 of one pair present.  Then the sum of the two residues  is then a solution. There was a slight error in the solution which I have editted.

Comment: Even then, there are still $p$ grouped resides (holes), because you eliminated residue $p$ but not $ p +1$. IE We could have the residues $1, 2, \ldots p-2, p-1,  p+1$ which doesn't immediately lead to a contradiction. Can you work through that part again?  (For this reason, this solution is a $0^+$ to me.)

Comment: @CalvinLin I paired it adding up to $-1$ instead of $0$ Then there are $p-1$ holes.

Comment: Ah, With the edits, then this PP is fine. (Cleaning up the presentation would be helpful,)